# Are scripts and images loaded synchronously or ansynchronously?

Tags: javascript, html

It's a very basic question - are scripts and images loaded synchronously or ansynchronously in webpages (such as what happens in ajax requests) ? I'm talking about including of images and scripts the regular html way - 

and

I was just wondering how browsers react to including relatively large files such as jQuery(which is about 2mb last I checked) or other big libraries or big images , should I worry that this will get my users stuck for several seconds upon connecting to my website ? I specifically want to know about the jQuery overhead since I'm considering using it for a small project...

Comment: If you load jQuery from a CDN like Google's then the chances go way up  that it's already in client browser caches.

Comment: jQuery is not 2Mb - v1.7.2 is 247Kb with comments and 93Kb minified.  Over the wire that goes down considerably to less than that once the server gzips it for the browser.

Comment: @SLaks - Where did that figure come from? Minified and gzipped?

Comment: Sorry either they made big improvements lately or I was just plain ignorant about jQuery's size . Even without the gzip , 93kb sounds very small for such a big library , at least in my opinion.

Comment: 93kb is the minified but uncompressed size. The library uncompressed and unminified is 247kb. But you can get it down to 32kb trivially with minification and gzip. These numbers are listed on jQuery.com main page...

Comment: @user1032663: Remember that we're talking about *text* here; it isn't like jQuery is some big binary. 2 MB for a *JavaScript* library would actually be ridiculously huge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images are loaded asynchronously and possibly concurrently. Don't bother about them, just make them as small as possible and use CSS sprites.

Scripts are blocking, i.e. you cannot load next script before you finished downloading the previous one. This is understandable since there might be some inter-script dependencies.

What you typically do is compressing and minifying all JavaScript resources into one file which you include at the bottom of your page. This way the page is nicely rendered giving good user experience and the scripts loads at the end. After all, you typically run scripts not earlier then on DOM ready event.

And BTW [jQuery minified](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) is only around 93K. And if you use the link above, it will most likely be cached in the browser once and for all.

Comment: I love all these drastically different claims on this very page about the size of jQuery.

Comment: @Oded: Fair point; I just thought it was funny to see all these seemingly contradictory claims—"jQuery is 32K", "jQuery is 94K", "jQuery is 500K", "jQuery is 2M"—competing in one place, without anyone really qualifying it until you posted that link.

Comment: @DanTao - I absolutely agree.

Answer (score 1):

- As soon as the server sends the DOM, the browser can show the
  website.
- Images are loaded asynchroneously, large images therefore appear
  slowly on slow connections
- jQuery is 32kb
- scripts load one by one, not at the same time

Comment: Actually the server just sends html, it's the browser that parses it into DOM.

Comment: Thanks . Oops about jQuery's size , did they make improvements lately or did I just have a completely wrong idea about it's size? I remember downloading about a year ago a jQuery library that was about 2mb but maybe that was just a dream:)

Answer (score 1):

To add to what's been said, there *are* script-loading libraries out there that do load scripts concurrently but still ensure that they are *executed* in order they appear. One that I've used and would recommend is [head.js](http://headjs.com/). It offers a very simple interface (the below is copied from the library's website):

```
head.js("/path/to/jquery.js", "/google/analytics.js", "/js/site.js", function() {
   // all done
});
```

Also, to clarify the confusion about jQuery's size... as of version 1.7.2:

- Unminified and uncompressed it is **275 KB**.
- Minified it is **95 KB**.
- Minified and compressed it is about **34 KB** (this is the value you see on jQuery's website).

The last option is the one you'd realistically be using on a production website; so your fears of users needing to download a 2 MB library can be put to rest.

Answer (score 0):

script *blocks* are synchronous (but they could contain asynchronous code)
image loading is asynchronous

Answer (score -1):

I think that the normal behavior for HTML is to load all the files (images and scripts) synchronously.

It is possible though to write a small inline JavaScript that loads files asynchronously.